# Can’t identify the kanij in 人の上には〇てぬぞ

Tags: kanji, calligraphy

I was reading, and one line came up as

> 人の上には〇てぬぞ

and for the life of me, I can't figure out what the sixth character is supposed to be. Because of font, I thought it might be a way of writing 之 , but that doesn't seem to make sense with the rest of the sentence. The full line is

> よく聞け、下の者の気持ちも知らねば、人の上には〇てぬぞ

[image: Picture of line of Japanese writing: "人の上には？てぬぞ”]

Comment: It is 立. (I need more text to finish this comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @droooze says in the comment section, this is a cursive rendering of 立 (see [here](https://moji.tekkai.com/zoom/%E7%AB%8B/page.html) or [here](https://1jp.tokyo/kanji/ra-wa/27.html)).

[image]